# one-tap google en kotlin y jetpack compose (para un novato)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-api, jetpack-compose

quisiera realizar un login con google para eso realice una función composable llamada `MainScreen` en la cual tiene un botón, el cual tiene un evento click que por el momento solo me genera un log, pero bueno he intentado seguir varios tutoriales pero todo se me hace difil de entender, ya realice la configuración en la consola de google, traje y pegue mi key al archivo `strings.xml` también realice la implementación de google service en el archivo grandle y la verdad después de eso no se que más hacer no encuentro algún tutorial que explique por completo, alguna ayuda? que necesito? o como debo proceder, soy bastante nuevo con kotlin y con jetpack compose.

archivo strings.xml

```xml
<string name="auth_key">miclaveunicayapreciada.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
```

gradle

```
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0")
```

```
    val token = stringResource(R.string.auth_key)
    val context = LocalContext.current

Column () {
// otros componentes XD
        Button(onClick = {
            Log.d("Scape dev", "Funciona el pinche click")
        }) {
            Text("Ingresar con google")
        }
    }
```

y pues cree un un archivo GoogleUserMode.kt ahí trate de implementar lo que vi en varios tutoriales, pero no me fue muy bien y otro llamado GoogleUserModel que es un data class

```
class MainScreenViewModel:ViewModel() {
    fun signInWithGoogleCredential () {
        
    }

}
```

y pues el data class

```
data class GoogleUserModel(
    val name: String?,
    val email:String?
)
```

cuando comencé, pensé que seria poco código, que a lo más seria una petición a un servidor o lo más dos, pero creo que es algo bastante ambicioso y no me quiero rendir, tal vez si pueden ayudarme con algún consejo donde ir buscando y voy actualizando lo que iré haciendo aquí.

Comment: Recuerda que las preguntas que buscar libros o recursos externos es motivo de cierre. ¿Puedes cargar tu código en la pregunta para que eso no suceda? No olvides ocultar las credenciales.